# Find the stationary points of a log equation

Tags: calculus

y=In(x^2+1)-x

Stuck on this question anyone able to give me step by step solving?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also this looks like a homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

We have \begin{align*}\frac{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}y}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x} &= \frac{1}{x^2+1}\frac{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x}(x^2+1)-1 \qquad \text{(by the chain rule)} \\ &= \frac{2x}{x^2+1}-1\end{align*} so, at the stationary points, we have \begin{align*}\frac{2x}{x^2+1}-1 = 0 &\iff 2x = x^2+1 \\ &\iff (x-1)^2 = 0 \\ &\iff x=1\end{align*} Therefore, the only stationary point is $(1,\ln(2)-1)$ (and you can go on to show that it is a point of inflexion).